# Is it possible to use multiple queries using RTK Query in the same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

So this project is fetching data from restcountries API. On the index page, the initial value is fetching all countries' data and displays it as cards. The endpoint to get all countries' data is `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all`. Also on the index page, there is 2 more filter, the first one is search country by fullName and the endpoint is `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/{name}?fullText=true`, and then filter by regions with endpoint `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/{region}` and I think I've successfully implemented this using useEffect to fetch the data, here is the code and here's [live demo](https://thunderous-cat-94f20a.netlify.app/)

```jsx
// Let's pretend there is an import here
export const ListOfCountries = ({ cca3 }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [apiUrl, setApiUrl] = useState("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [optionUrl, setOptionUrl] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
        setErrorMessage("");
        setData(response.data);
        if (searchQuery === "") {
          optionUrl
            ? setApiUrl(optionUrl)
            : setApiUrl("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
        } else {
          setApiUrl(
            `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${encodeURI(
              searchQuery
            )}?fullText=true`
          );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setErrorMessage(
          `${searchQuery} is not found, plesase enter full name of country`
        );
        if (searchQuery === "") setApiUrl("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
      }
    })();
  }, [apiUrl, searchQuery, optionUrl]);

  return (
    <>
      <Flex>
        <Input
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search for a country..."
          onChange={useDebounce((e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value), 700)}
        />
        <FilterBox setApiUrl={setApiUrl} setOptionUrl={setOptionUrl} />
      </Flex>

      <Flex>
        {errorMessage ? (
          <p>{errorMessage}</p>
        ) : (
          data?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <Link to={`/country/${item.cca3}`} key={index}>
                <PreviewCard item={item} />
              </Link>
            );
          })
        )}
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
};
```

And now I'm trying to implement this same feature using RTK Query, so I'm creating 2 queries [countries.js](https://github.com/aroyan/countries-lists/blob/dev/src/features/countries.js) and using them in [ListOfCountries.jsx](https://github.com/aroyan/countries-lists/blob/dev/src/components/ListOfCountries.jsx). To get all countries data is works as expected but when I tried to use `useGetCountryByFullNameQuery` the data is not displayed and still render all of countries data. I printed it to console and the data of some specific country is actually displayed. How to display them like the one I got by using `useEffect` above?

Answer (score 0):

In `Flex` component where links are displayed, you are always mapping over `data` from `useGetallCountriesQuery`. When `searchQuery` is not empty and `searchData` is not `undefined` use `searchData` else use `data` to map.